# Reading Strings From An Uploaded File

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a file containing a column of numbers that I wish to read into a string. The file, however, is not being imported using a location on my hard disk, rather it's being uploaded via a FileUpload control.

I was wondering if there is a way I could read in the text from this file. I've looked into StreamReader, but that requires I have a string that's the path name of the file.

Is there another way around this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471209/how-to-read-a-file-from-internet :)

Answer (score 3):

A `StreamReader` requires a stream, not a path.  Based on the documentation on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx) you can use the FileContent member of the FileUpload control and feed that into a StreamReader.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with ASP.NET (C# is just a programming language) the FileUpload control will save the file on the server in a temporary location that is made available to your session.

Then all you have to do is open the temporary file and read it's contents (using a StreamReader or something else)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of: [Looping trough lines of txt file uploaded via FileUpload control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149987/looping-trough-lines-of-txt-file-uploaded-via-fileupload-control)

Which sugested this solution, to pass a FileUpload.FileContent to the StreamReader and looping through the contents:

```
{

    FileUpload fu = FileUpload1; 
    if (fu.HasFile)  
    {
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fu.FileContent);
                        do
                        {
                            string textLine = reader.ReadLine();

                            // do your coding 
                            //Loop trough txt file and add lines to ListBox1  

                        }
                        while (reader.Peek() != -1);
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    }
}
```

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, please flag it as such instead of reposting the answer.